# Corrupted sudoers file on long running Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sudo, filesystem-corruption, raspbian

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 as a home server to run my scheduled scripts from. For the past few months my scripts have run fine, but yesterday I got a database paging error which seemed strange.

Attempting to restart my service this morning via remote connection, I got the following corrupted/replaced characters when I tried to restart the service, which requires `sudo`:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: No such file or directory
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
me@myserver:~$ ls
Backups  Code  Misc
me@myserver:~$ cd /usr
me@myserver:/usr$ cd lib
me@myserver:/usr/lib$ cd sudo
me@myserver:/usr/lib/sudo$ ls
grkup_file.s?  sesh  sudoers.s?  sudo_noexec.so  sy?tem_gvoup.so
me@myserver:/usr/lib/sudo$
```

I also get strange errors on other commands, e.g.

```
man: can't execute pager: Structure needs cleaning
man: command exited with status 255: (cd /usr/lib && LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual pa
e fsck(8) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for
help or q to quit)$PM Manual page fsck(8) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?
 (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=fsck(8) pager -s)
```

Should I be worried about having picked up a virus that is doing this or is it just corruption? Will a reboot be safe? Is there any way for me to fix the `sudoers` file without `sudo` which I can't use? What will be the most useful information I should find out to work out the extent of the problem (e.g. any clever greps or such I could run here)?

I have a semi-recent backup so I don't need to do any emergency data recovery but I'm curious to find out how I could go about diagnosing this before resorting to restoring.

Comment: IIRC storage on a Rapsberry is just a SD card, and yours can be starting to wear out.

Comment: SD cards have a finite lifetime and weren't expected to have a live OS running from them. Raspberry Pi devices are notorious for killing SD cards. It is more likely that you need to replace the card and do a (fresh) reinstall.

Comment: SD cards have a lifetime measured in decades these days. No amount of Raspi is going to wear our your SD card.